# Error: "wrong-number-of-arguments quote 0" when opening files with ".txt" extension

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Every time I try to create or visit a file with a ".txt" extension, I get a stack trace like the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments quote 0)
  quote()
  set-auto-mode-0(quote nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer file.txt> "~/path/to/file.txt" nil nil "~/path/to/file.txt" (24122033 2049))
  find-file-noselect("/home/me/path/to/file.txt" nil nil)
  ido-file-internal(raise-frame)
  ido-find-file()
  call-interactively(ido-find-file nil nil)
```

The buffer "file.txt" is open, however, in fundamental mode. This happens whether I use `ido_find-file` or `M-x find file`.

I tried to fix this by adding the following line in my `init.el` file:

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt$" . text-mode))`

...and I've changed the `txt` to `[tT][xX][tT]`, switched out a `\\'` for the `$`, and tried `fundamental-mode` instead of `text-mode`; but no combination of changes seems to make the error go away.

I'm working with GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2), on xubuntu linux.

I presume the error starts with `set-auto-mode()`, but I don't know that for sure, and I don't know why the parens would be empty there. Has anyone else had this problem, or know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an auto-mode-alist issue, evaluate the following to confirm which mode Emacs is getting from that:

```
(assoc-default "foo.txt" auto-mode-alist 'string-match)
```

If it's `nil`, that's certainly the problem, and you do have a problem with your `auto-mode-alist` configuration.

It's probably not that, though -- there are a bunch of other things Emacs tries in `set-auto-mode`, so you likely need to narrow it down.

Try this:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `files` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `foo.txt` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Having evaluated the functions (n.b. you could really just evaluate `set-auto-mode`), you should now get a far more detailed stack trace when you hit the debugger, so you'll be able to figure out exactly *where* in `set-auto-mode` the call to `set-auto-mode-0` is happening, and consequently which mechanism is resulting in a `nil` value for the major mode symbol.

(If you're unsure how to proceed from there, paste the stack trace into the question.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is coming from a faultly local variables declaration in your file `/home/me/path/to/file.txt`.  Do you have a local variables declaration in that file, and does it perhaps contain a quote (`'`) that should not be there?

But I agree with the good advice that @phils gave, for tracking this down.  There are a few different ways in which `set-auto-mode` can try to determine the mode.  You will need to find out which one was being used (unless perhaps my guess helps).